# Excel Table with VBA code resetting columns when new row added

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel table that uses a VBA code to create a checked/unchecked boxed when double clicked in columns M and N. The problem I have is that when I add a new row to the table all the cells in row M & N turn into a checked box instead of leaving the cell how it was before a new row was added.. would anyone know how to fix this?

- VBA Code being used

```vb
    Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("M:N")) Is Nothing Then

    Select Case Target
    Case Is = Chr(254)
    Target = Chr(168)
    Cancel = True
    Case Is = Chr(168)
    Target = Chr(254)
    Cancel = True
    End Select

    End If
    End Sub
```

Haven't tried anything yet as I am only new to Excel and VBA coding

Comment: Is there `Worksheet_Change`? Is there any formula in Col M and N?

Comment: Hi, there is no formula in col M or N  and no code in worksheet_change

Comment: A screenshot is helpful to know the issue.

Comment: Code is working for me. Ho do you insert the new row?